# Trouble turning java project into jar file

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I've made a project consisting of some java files, an images folder with a few images and a data folder with a few text files.  Everything works perfectly when I compile the program and run it through terminal.  I decided to try and turn it into a jar file, so after lots of research I managed to do it, including using a manifest file.  Here is what I type into terminal to do it:

```
jar cvfm Program.jar manifest.txt *.class images data
```

Giving this output:

```
added manifest  
adding: a.class (in = 500) (out = 500) (deflated 50%)  
adding: b.class (in = 500) (out = 500) (deflated 50%)  
adding: images/ (in = 0) (out = 0) (stored 0%)  
adding: images/a.png (in = 500) (out = 500) (deflated 50%)  
adding: images/b.png (in = 500) (out = 500) (deflated 50%)  
adding: data/ (in = 0) (out = 0) (stored 0%)  
adding: data/a.txt (in = 500) (out = 500) (deflated 50%)
```

The only lines of which stand out being the images/ and data/ which have in, out, stored =0.

This works and it lists all of the files correctly within the jar file.  The jar file even runs perfectly when in the correct directory of the program, however if I remove it from that directory, it no longer can find any of the resource files (images and data) and I have no idea why. It may be a way that I am referencing them in my code or that the resource files aren't attached properly, but I'm not really sure.  My manifest file consists of:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Main-Class: Strike
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do know that there's IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) that automate this process for you, right?

Comment: @user1329572 in a lot of situations you'll want the build to be achievable without the IDE. If you need Eclipse to build your code, there is a problem somewhere IMO (esp. in corporate environments).

Comment: Please also post the output of running the `jar` command and the actual error/exception that you're seeing.

Comment: @Romain, I'm not recommending OP become reliant upon an IDE for builds..all I'm saying is that there are tools out there that make it much easier to deploy an application.

Comment: @Romain: in that case, you would use a build tool, eg Ant. Building a corporate project from the command line without using a tool would be ludacris.

Comment: @Buffalo I cannot agree more. By blanket-covering by saying "The IDE does it for you" is not appropriate. In the end it's actually not even relevant to the question.

Comment: Well apparently it should just be one line of code to build it, which I listed in the post.  I would have thought it would work, but it can't read any of the resource files for some reason.

Comment: @Romain, "In the end it's actually not even relevant to the question". I'm sorry, but that couldn't be further from the truth.

Comment: What ***is*** the question?  The OP forgot to ask one.

Comment: @user1329572 How is "how to build the jar" related to "how to access ressources from within the jar"? I fail to see the link, sorry.

Comment: @Romain, It's in the question title, "**Trouble turning java project into jar file**", which my comment answers and, therefore makes it relevant.

Comment: bottom line: are the resources added to the jar? unzip the archive and tell us.

Answer (score 3):

If your resource files (images, etc ...) are stored in the jar file, you should access them with

```
inputstream = getClass()
              .getClassLoader()
              .getResourceAsStream("Path to your file in the jar file");
```

Comment: You should actually *always* refer to resources that can be found in the classpath in this way, instead of using straight-out `File`s.

Comment: Heeeey. This could be my problem. I'm just using a File class to load them.  I'll try this way.  Thanks heaps guys.

Comment: Hey, so i adjusted my code to this:
InputStream is = getClass()......AsStream("file.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
However it still can not find the file.  Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: Wait, i think its because i was checking to see if the file existed first, but i removed that and it seems to work... :)

Comment: Nope. Still can't seem to find the image... Strange

Comment: Where is the file in the jar archive ? Please post the code you use to access it (with the resource file path used)

Comment: ALL WORKING NOW. THANKS EVERYONE :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a classpath problem. When you launch the JAR in your project directory, in fact you are reading resources from the filesystem, not from the archive.

To read resources from the classpath use [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/foo.png");
```

And put `foo.png` inside an `images` directory in the final archive like you already do. Note the leading slash in `/images/foo.png` . Quoting the doc

> An absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name
>   using this algorithm:
>
> 1. If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>      the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> 2. Otherwise,
>      the absolute name is of the following form: `modified_package_name/name`
>      Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object
>      with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

If you don't want to use an IDE to build your project, there are tools like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("...");` is better I think. I already met the case where resource file access didn't work properly with only `getClass().getResourceAsStream("...");` (actually, I don't really know why)

Comment: According to [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) there should be no difference. Can you provide the code to show a different behavior? I've always used the Class method since it saves typing :P

Comment: It's an old code, but I'll try to find it tonight and post it here