# NoSuchFileException in .jar but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, embedded-resource, nosuchfileexception

When i compile and run my program in Eclipse, is runs without exceptions. But when i export it to an runnable jar or an normal jar it does not find my settings file.

My path is:

```
String path= "src/settings/settings.ini";
```

In eclipse it runs without exception, but in a jar, it throws the exception immediately .

How is it possible to make the jar just work as it is in eclipse?

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090882/trouble-turning-java-project-into-jar-file

Comment: *"it throws the exception"* What exception?  Please always copy/paste exception output (the stacktrace).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while inside jar the file is no more physical file, so you may need to read it as Stream

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("settings/settings.ini");
```

considering that settings.ini is under classpath (runtime) at specified path

Comment: I find `getResource(String)` for an URL is not only more reliable for getting access to an [embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) (in that the `InputStream` returned is typically not repositionable), but also shorter to type. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the ini file is located in the jar archive, read it like this :

```
inputstream = getClass()
          .getClassLoader()
          .getResourceAsStream("settings/settings.ini");
```

Else if it's located outside of your jar archive, you should move or copy your ini file in **./settings/settings.ini** (relatively to the current working directory of your application).